# How to reduce the height of AlertDialog which includes a slider?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a **AlertDialog** which is included a slider (especially `SfRangeSlider()`).

My AlertDialog Image:

[image]

There is a problem with the height of AlertDialog.

My question is how to reduce the dialog size including the `SfRangeSlider()`.

My `_showDialog()` as below:

```
void _showDialog() async {
   await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('총톤수'),
        content: SfRangeSlider(
          min: 0.0,
          max: 100.0,
          values: _values,
          interval: 10,
          showTicks: false,
          showLabels: true,
          enableTooltip: true,
          minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
          onChanged: (SfRangeValues values) {
            setState(() {
              _values = values;
            });
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
            child: const Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you don't want to use static height**: you can wrap your `SfRangeSlider` with `Column` and set its `mainAxisSize` to `min`:

```
showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('총톤수'),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SfRangeSlider(
            min: 0.0,
            max: 100.0,
            values: _values,
            interval: 10,
            showTicks: false,
            showLabels: true,
            enableTooltip: true,
            minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
            onChanged: (SfRangeValues values) {
               setState(() {
                 _values = values;
               });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
          child: const Text('OK'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Comment: @HappyCoding was it what you want?

Comment: Appreciate your answer. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `SfRangeSlider` with SizedBox and provide height.

```dart
void _showDialog() async {
   await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('총톤수'),
        content: SizedBox(
           height: x, // x= hard-coded value or you can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *.5 ,,50% height 
           child: SfRangeSlider(
             min: 0.0,
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. It works perfectly.